# Empty first page and missing begin document

Tags: packages, preamble

I'm getting the error: **LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.**

Everything in my document seemed to working earlier today, but now I have an empty first page with nothing but a page number at the top right, and an error saying:
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

I don't really know what's important to post here if I could get any guidance I would appreciate it so much. I've been working on a paper for the better part of a year and don't know what to do. I know I'm including way too many packages. I inherited this paper and don't know what I need and what I don't. This all started earlier today when I was trying to align some equations.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{myOrange}{HTML}{DB5800}
\arrayrulecolor{myOrange}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\hypersetup{ 
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=black,
    pdftitle={Title},
    pdfauthor={Author},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\citelinktext}[2]{%
  \hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

% Install packages
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{my}{font=*/*/*/sc/*}
\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{500}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\usepackage{helvet}
\newenvironment{fontHel}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}{\par}
\newcommand*{\fontTimes}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\fontHelv}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{outlines}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % to increase default height of table rows
\usepackage{tabularx} % for text wrapping in tables
\usepackage{adjustbox} % resizes table if it gets too wide
\usepackage{enumitem} % to access properties of itemize env.
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable} % for multi-page table
\usepackage{lscape} % for landscape table
\usepackage{afterpage} % for table
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{geometry} % for modifying page size/margins
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for text strikethrough (command: \sout{text})
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\newcommand*\sq{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}}}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage{color} % For highlighting
\newcommand{\revision}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\revrev}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
\newcommand\fnsep{\textsuperscript{,}}
\let\oldFootnote\footnote
\newcommand\nextToken\relax

\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
    \oldFootnote{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnote}

\newcommand\isFootnote{%
    \ifx\footnote\nextToken\textsuperscript{,}\fi}
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
  \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
  \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}




\begin{document}
```

the error log I'm getting is:

```
l.1 n
     %%
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
```

I'm panicking. Please let me know what I need to post to get help?

Comment: Unrelated but your preamble is overloaded. Clean it up, remove obsolete, unused and duplicate packages.

Comment: `\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files` only use this in documents written before 1993 . why prevent `amsmath` being loaded `\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}` then attempt to load it (twice) with `\usepackage{amsmath}` ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by the OP inadventertently editing the class file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading the log file incorrectly, because you refer the tail of the error `l.1 n` `%%` and the message after the error is ignored: `Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!`. The log file shows you the context of the error an you don't show it in your listing.
The full log file looks like this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./your-document.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
(./iopart.cls

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 n
     %%
?
```

and if you continue running TeX despite the error:

```
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
```

At the opening parentesis `(`, TeX opens the file `./iopart.cls`. Then the LaTeX error is reported at line 1 of this file at the position 1 just before the `%%`. Then you can simply look to this file and you can found the `n` letter here. It was saved here probably as a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a dummy. I accidentally added a random character in my iopart.cls file. I still can't seem to get my equations aligned, but at least the document begins again.